# How can I mock/fake the existence of a file using rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, mocking, rspec

This is what I have:

```
it "should be able to get a valid directory path" do  
   @asset.some_file_path.should == "/something/test.jpg"
end
```

The problem is that some_file_path returns "/not_here_yet.jpg" if there is no existing file.

```
def some_file_path
  if File.exists(self.my_image_path)
    return my_image_path
  else
    return "/not_here_yet.jpg
  end
end
```

I don't really want to create a new file in my tests. Is there a way for me to fake the existence of the file?

I'm thinking something in the lines of :

```
it "should be able to get a valid directory path" do  
   AwesomeFakeFileCreator.create(@asset.my_image_path)
   @asset.some_file_path.should == "/something/test.jpg"
end
```

Is this possible? How can I do such a thing?

Edit: I looked a bit at [FakeFS](http://github.com/defunkt/fakefs) but I'm not sure it answers my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something on the lines of

```
it "should be able to get a valid directory path" do  
  File.stub!(:exists?).and_return(true)
  @asset.stub!(:my_image_path).and_return("/something/test.jpg")
  @asset.some_file_path.should == "/something/test.jpg"
end
```

Comment: Could you detail a bit what this is doing?

Comment: The first line is stubbing out that the file exists returns true and the second line is stubbing out my_image_path method on asset object and returns the file path, which your some_file_path method will return in that case, i.e. which the whole spec example is about. In summary, return the path if it exists.

Comment: Not that you have to keep me happy or anything -- I didn't ask the question -- but I'm afraid that I didn't understand that.

Comment: @Shadowfirebird If you point out the bit that you didn't understand then I will be able to address the issue more specifically :)

Comment: Assuming my_image_path is simply a string attribute, there's no reason to stub my_image_path. Simply stubbing File.exists should do the trick.

Comment: @Dave Sims True if that's the case

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can fake with the correct path of your File. Fake for each file that you want to return the path

```
  it "should be able to get a valid directory path" do  
    File.stub!(:exists?).with("my_image_path.jpg").and_return("my_image_path.jpg")
    @asset.some_file_path.should == "my_image_path.jpg"
  end
```

Answer (score -2):

This is probably a highly unhelpful answer as I am only just getting my head around automated testing, myself, but:

As I understand it, you only need to test two conditions: file exists, and file does not exist?

Testing non-existence is easy enough: create an Asset with a my_image_path that doesn't exist, and check the function returns '/not_here_yet.jpg'.

Surely you can test the other case in the same way?  create an empty file with a .jpg extension, then an Asset that points to it, and check that the function returns the correct name?

Comment: I don't want to create files on the fly. Tests would be slower and I would have to be extra carefull creating/deleting the file.